# Not able to access MongoDB properties or functions

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Im trying to access properties or functions inside `mongoose.connection` to retrieve `DeleteMany` or `DropCollection` methods, but I'm not able to.
I am starting the express.js server inside the mongoose connection.

```
mongoose
.connect(connection, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(() => {
    mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection('database');
    console.log('connected');
    app.listen(5000);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

What am i doing wrong? I've tried searching for the solution, and I know that I can't delete collection using `Mongoose`, I can only delete the data using `MongoDb`. Can anyone help me understand, what I'm missing while deleting the collection when the server runs?

Comment: is `database` a collection name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete all Records using `deleteMany` in `mongoose`.

You will have to specify `model` of the collection to apply operation on

For deleting collection

```js
MyModel.collection.drop();
```

Deleting all records

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
  
// Database connection
mongoose.connect(connectionUrl, { 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}); 
  
// MyCollection model 
const MyCollection = mongoose.model('MyCollection', { 
    prop1: { type: String }, 
    prop2: { type: Number } 
}); 
  
// Function call 
MyCollection.deleteMany({}).then(function(){ 
    console.log("all records deleted"); // Success 
}).catch(function(error){ 
    console.log(error); // Failure 
});
```